# ¿Se puede insertar video de Youtube privado en mi web?

Tags: php, html, youtube

Se puede poner un video privado en Youtube pero insertarlo en mi web con los permisos correspondientes?
Quizás estoy volando mucho pero disculpen si es una pregunta ridícula.
Gracias.

NOTA: Esto es para crear un canal privado y darle el acceso solo a los usuarios que paguen, pero en teoria una de las formas es darle privilegios manualmente desde el canal de youtube a la cuenta en cuestion.

Comment: Hola, ¿Cuáles permisos son los que deseas poner?, si es privado solo tu podrás ver este video. . Recuerda revisar [ask], puedes obtener reputación  y realizar este tipo de preguntas en el [chat], saludos.

Comment: Recuerda mejorar la pregunta y solicitar su reapertura para que no se pierda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los videos son privados por una razón. Solo los puedes ver tú.

En el caso de que lo insertes en tu página los demás no podrán verlo.

Cómo sugieren en [Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29408802/13419694):

Mejor establece la visibilidad del vídeo como **no listado**. Así podrán ver el vídeo incrustado o a través de su enlace.

Comment: Agradecería que explicaran el voto negativo. La pregunta no es mala, es simple y no se había hecho antes.

Comment: Hola, perdon el voto negativo fue sin querer

Comment: @Julio también me pasó. Por suerte se puede cambiar el voto o si volves a tocar el mismo botón de deshace.

Comment: Si igual no soy muy bueno manejando esto, pero ya te aparece bien? tengo q hacer algo mas? jaja para no dejarte con mala calificacion innecesariamente.

Comment: **@Mateo, Si respondes a este tipo de preguntas que no se realizan con base en [ask], el usuario regularmente [volverá a preguntar de esta forma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/583359/se-puede-marcar-una-zona-en-google-map-desde-android-studio)** (ya realizó otras similares) y de alguna forma se está contribuyendo a tener información de baja calidad en el sitio.